# Картинка на задний фон

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я хочу на задний фон в body поставить изображение,как это сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый

Answer (score 2):

Где `imgPath` путь к необходимой картинке

**jQuery**

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgPath + ')');
```

**Vanillia.js**

```
document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + imgPath + ')';
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background-image: url(/*тут путь к картинке */);
}
```

Comment: По типу этого? $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + /images/1.jpg + ')');

Comment: `imgPath` это переменная которую необходимо сначала обновить. 

Например вот так: `var imgPath = '/images/1.jpg';`

Comment: Если хотите использовать просто строку то правильно будет так: `$('body').css('background-image', 'url(/images/1.jpg)')`